# JQuery LiveValidations with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/augustl/live-validations/wiki to check if the form field entered is valid or not. How do i disable the live validation for keypress and instead make it only fire when the submit button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to handle this at the submit event?

Comment: Actually it already does that. I just don't want it checking on every keypress. How do i disable that?

Comment: on keypress of each input element call jquery validation method element().   look it up this allows you to call validation code 1 element at a time